# Postgres Query JSON array of objects to return properties as columns

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a Postgres `addresses` table with rows such as:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"name": "Scott", "addresses": [{"city": "London", "street": "street 1"}, {"city": "Berlin", "street": "street 2"}]} |
| 2 | {"name": "Tiger", "addresses": [{"city": "Tokyo", "street": "street 3"}, {"city": "Zurich", "street": "street 4"}]} |
| 3 | {"name": "Foooo", "addresses": [{"city": "Paris", "street": "street 5"}]} |

where **data** is `JSON`

What query would produce the following result

| id | name | city | street |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Scott | London | street 1 |
| 1 | Scott | Berlin | street 2 |
| 2 | Tiger | Tokyo | street 3 |
| 2 | Tiger | Zurich | street 4 |
| 3 | Foooo | Paris | street 5 |

It looks like `json_array_elements` is relevant here but I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using `json_array_elements` :

```
select id, json_data->>'name' as name, json_data->>'city' as city, json_data->>'street' as street
from addresses, json_array_elements (data->'addresses') as json_data
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/u7lpR7H1)

Comment: Thanks, I amended the table name that I provided after you posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, data->>'name', t."City", t."Street"
from addresses, lateral 
   (select * from jsonb_to_recordset(data->'addresses') 
         as x("City" text, "Street" text) ) as t;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cIBGPNgB)

EDIT: You edited your question after my reply. Here is edited version:

```
select id, data->>'name', t.city, t.street
from addresses, lateral 
   (select * from jsonb_to_recordset(data->'addresses') 
         as x(city text, street text) ) as t;
```

[Dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/U9dmbrQq)